# Image from library does not show - image from camera does

Tags: javascript, android, html, security, filereader

Using this popular code from the internet:

code

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" />
<output id="list"></output>
<script>
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

        // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

            // Only process image files.
            if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                continue;
            }

            var reader = new window.FileReader();

            // Closure to capture the file information.
            reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                return function (e) {
                    // Render thumbnail.
                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                                        '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                    document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
                };
            })(f);

            // Read in the image file as a data URL.
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

On my android tablet the image only shows when taking a Picture with the camera instead of choosing an image from the filesystem.

On my laptop (where I only can choose files from the filesystem) the image is shown.

Is there somekind of security issue here?

Using alerts to check how far the script runs on the android device, I can see that the script runs fine without any errors.

Android device is running Android version `4.2.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try this code you i have track the issue.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" />
            <output id="list">
            </output>
        </body>
        <script>
            function handleFileSelect(evt) {
                var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
                // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
                for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
                    console.log("for call");

                    var reader = new window.FileReader();

                    // Closure to capture the file information.
                    reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                        return function(e) {
                            // Render thumbnail.
                            var span = document.createElement('span');
                            console.log(e.target.result);
                            var spl = e.target.result.split(",");
                            console.log("data:image/png;base64," + spl[1]);
                            var el = "data:image/png;base64," + spl[1];

                            span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', el, '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                            document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
                        };
                    })(f);

                    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
                    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
                }
            }

            document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
        </script>

    </html>
```